# Enviar dato por ajax a controlador - symfony

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony3, symfony

Estoy desarrollando un sistema web de gestion de turnos con symfony 3.4, jquery y ajax. En un formulario, el usuario selecciona una sede y una fecha y debe presionar un boton para obtener los turnos disponibles. No puedo obtener la respuesta del servidor o bien no me esta ejecutando el pedido. Es la primera vez que aplico ajax.

El script que me debe enviar los datos por POST es la siguiente:

```
    //AJAX CON JQUERY
    $("#actualizar").on("click",consultarTurnos);

function consultarTurnos()
    {
        var sede = $("#sede").val();
        var fecha = $("#fecha").val();
$.ajax
        ({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/turnos',
            data: datos,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (respuesta)
            {
               // alert('la respuesta es ' + respuesta); 
                $("#respuesta").html(data); 
            },
            error : function(xhr, status) 
            {
                alert('hay error');
                //alert('ERROR -> '. status);
            }

        });



    }

</script>
```

El codigo html es el siguiente:

```
               <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                            <select class="form-control" 
                                    name="sede" 
                                    id="sede"
                                    required=""
                                    onchange="guardarSede();">
                                <option disabled selected hidden>Seleccione la sede</option>
                                <option value="1">Predio UNL - ATE</option>
                                <option value="2">Rectorado</option>
                                <option value="3">Esperanza</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                                        <input class="form-control"
                                               type="text" 
                                               id = "datepicker"
                                               required=""
                                               placeholder="Seleccione la fecha"
                                               onchange="guardarFecha();"
                                               disabled
                                               />

                           <textarea
                                    name="fecha" 
                                    id="fecha"
                                    style = "display:none"
                                    onchange="habilitarTurno();">
                           </textarea>

                                        <!--  -->
                       </div>

<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-default"
                                name ="actualizar"
                                id="actualizar"
                                type="button">Actualizar </button>
                    </div>
```

El metodo que debe recibir la información y responder en formato json es la siguiente:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/turnos",name="turnos")
 */
public function buscarTurnos(Request $request)
{
    //var_dump($_GET);
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        $sede = $request->request->get('sede');
        $fecha = new \DateTime($request->request->get('fecha'));

        $db = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $qb = $db->createQueryBuilder();

        //escribo la consuLta
        $qb->select('t.dia,t.horario,t.cupo')
           ->from('ComensalesBundle:Turno','t')
           ->where('t.dia = :fecha')
           ->andWhere('t.sede = :sede')
           ->setParameter('fecha',$fecha)
           ->setParameter('sede',$sede)
           ;
        //genero
        $q = $qb->getQuery();
        //consulto
        //$resultado = $q->getResult();
        $resultado = $q->getArrayResult();
        //retorno
        return new JsonResponse($resultado);
    }
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('final'));
}
```

Ingresando a la consola del navegador, muestra lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Por lo que veo, se esta enviando por get la información pero no esta obteniendo la respuesta del servidor.

La consulta mysql de buscarTurnos() funciona correctamente y el metodo devuelve la respuesta en formato json como es esperado. Supongo que el error se encuentra en como uso ajax con jquery.
Cualquier colaboración sera eternamente agradecida.
Saludos
Cristian

Comment: Asumiendo que el código html y javascript los tienes juntos en un archivo twig. Me gustaría saber si tu código ajax llega en algún momento a devolverte el mensaje de error que has configurado o en todo caso que te devuelve.

Comment: No me devuelve ningun mensaje de error. Cuando lo pruebo coloco unos alert dentro del metodo consultarTurnos() y el metodo se ejecuta pero al llegar a $ajax no pasa nada mas. No retorna ni el mensaje de sucess ni el de error con el codigo

Comment: Este alert(datos); antes de llamar el ajax, si te manda el alert o tampoco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de revisar un poco tu código, creo que te has olvidado de algo muy puntual:

```
var sede = document.getElementById('sede'); //Aquí cambiaría por $("#sede") pero aún sin eso debería funcionar
var fecha = document.getElementById('fecha'); //Aquí cambiaría por $("#fecha") pero aún sin eso debería funcionar
var datos = {};
datos.sede = sede; //Aquí debería ser sede.val()
datos.fecha = fecha; //Aquí debería ser fecha.val()
alert(datos);
```

Espero te sirva y sino, me comentas como te fue para ver que otra cosa podría ser.

Algo más que creo debes modificar está aquí, en la sección del método del controller:

```
    $sede = $request->request->get('sede'); //Aquí yo uso $request->query->get('sede')
    $fecha = new \DateTime($request->request->get('fecha')); //Y aquí sería $request->query->get('fecha'), posteriormente la conversión a date
```

Finalmente, esta línea de código no se si está relacionada con otro método puesto que ha simple vista parece que sobreescribe el return del if del request.

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('final'));
```

En esta parte no estoy del todo seguro, puesto que no suelo usar anotaciones sino más bien un solo archivo routing de configuración global.

Cabe señalar que las sugerencias que te estoy dando están basadas en código 100% funcional, ya que también suelo usar symfony 3.4.10 y 4 para desarrollar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por los comentarios. Me fueron utiles. Igualmente sigo sin poder recibir datos. Modifique el posteo anterior por si lo puedes ver. Al hacer el envió por get, en consola muestra que fue enviado pero no esta recibiendo la información. Cualquier colaboración es bienvenida.

Comment: Hola @Cristhian. Muchas gracias por toda la ayuda, pude resolverlo y ahora funciona muy bien.

Comment: Que bueno saberlo, yo también me tome algo de tiempo para poder implementar ajax dentro de symfony, suerte en todo.